# Excel email comes in a different format unable to open Python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, smtplib

The goal is to send an email with excel attachment. 
I found an example online but not written for Excel format. 
It sends attachment but not like typical excel spreadsheet, so I am unable to open it.

Is it something I can modify in a code in order to receive .xlsx file?

[image]

```
# libraries to be imported 
import smtplib 
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText 
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase 
from email import encoders 

fromaddr = "From@gmail.com"
toaddr = "To@gmail.com"

# instance of MIMEMultipart 
msg = MIMEMultipart() 

# storing the senders email address   
msg['From'] = fromaddr 

# storing the receivers email address  
msg['To'] = toaddr 

# storing the subject  
msg['Subject'] = "Sending Attachement"

# string to store the body of the mail 
body = "Hello, This is Oleg and my attached file"

# attach the body with the msg instance 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 

# open the file to be sent  
filename = "FileName"
attachment = open("C:\\Mylocation\\FileName.xlsx", "rb") 

# instance of MIMEBase and named as p 
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream') 

# To change the payload into encoded form 
p.set_payload((attachment).read()) 

# encode into base64 
encoders.encode_base64(p) 

p.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 

# attach the instance 'p' to instance 'msg' 
msg.attach(p) 

# creates SMTP session 
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) 

# start TLS for security 
s.starttls() 

# Authentication 
s.login(fromaddr, "password") 

# Converts the Multipart msg into a string 
text = msg.as_string() 

# sending the mail 
s.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text) 

# terminating the session 
s.quit()
```

Comment: what happens if you change your `filename` variable to `"FileName.xlsx"` instead of just `"FileName"`

Comment: Oh! That was easy. Please, post an answer. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure! Sometimes its the small things that will drive you nuts coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is just a small error in your code! change your `filename` variable to `"FileName.xlsx"` instead of just `"FileName"`

I noticed that your file didn't have an extension, and since your `filename` variable didn't have an extension - that is how I quickly came to this conclusion. The [documentation for `add_header()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.message.html#email.message.Message.add_header) seems to use the file extensions as well.

Comment: Awesome!  Thank you